# Extrapolation of sample to population

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, extrapolation

How to extrapolate a sample of 10,000 rows to the entire population (100,000) in python. I did agglomerative clustering on the sample in python, stuck with extrapolating the result to the entire population.

Comment: Can you [post some code you are using](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show where it isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general rule.

For hierarchical clustering, this very much depends on your linkage, and **the clustering of a different sample or the whole population may be *very* different**. (For a starter, try a different sample and compare!)

Generalizing a clustering result to new data is usually *contradicting* the very assumptions made for the clustering. This is not classification, but explorative data analysis.

However, if you have found *good* clustering results, and you have verified them to be desirable, then you can **train a classifier on the cluster labels** to predict the cluster label of new data.